# Simple set inclusion question.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Reading [the completion theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Metric_Space)/Lemma_3), there is a step concerned to prove a set inclusion.

Let $\phi:A\rightarrow \tilde{A}$ be a mapping. The item $(2)$ of the proof shows that $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \implies x=y$. I do not understand why it is equivalent to say $A\subseteq \tilde{A}$. Can you clarify this for me? Has it anything to do with injectivity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's abuse of notation, really, since $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ contain objects of a different nature: $A$ consists of points in the original metric space, while $\tilde{A}$ consists of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of points in $A$. So you're right that it can't be set inclusion what they're trying to prove.

What they really mean (they allude to this just after the proof) is that $\tilde{A}$ *contains an isomorphic copy of* $A$, i.e., that $\phi$ is a bijection from $A$ to $\phi(A) \subseteq \tilde{A}$. To this end, they show, as you stated, that $\phi$ is injective, showing that $A$ can be embedded in $\tilde{A}$.

I have to say, I'm a bit confused as to why the article states later on that they're going to show that $\phi$ is injective. They already did.

Comment: So, items (2) and (4) showed that $\phi$ is an isometry such that it maps $(A,d)$ to $(\tilde{A},\tilde{d})$ in the form $(\phi(A),\tilde{d})$. From this, to show the denseness of $A$ in $\tilde{A}$, we should show that  the set $\phi(A)$ is dense in $\tilde{A}$? In my thoughts, $A$ is dense in $\tilde{A}$ if $closure(A)=\tilde{A}$, and the closure depends on limits points, which in turn depends on the metric. Logically, I cannot compare $(A,d)$ with $(\tilde{A},\tilde{d})$ directly. Instead this can be achieved with the intermediation of the isometry $\phi$.

Comment: So, is $A$ or is $\phi(A)$ that is dense in $\tilde{A}$???

Comment: The page states that $A$ is dense in $\tilde{A}$. But for me, it makes much more sense to think of $\phi(A)$ being dense in $\tilde{A}$. Is the proof I linked above as "over informal" as I am suspecting?

Comment: @Danmat It's informal, but also in line with how mathematicians think and write. See Terry Tao's blog post https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/. To use his lingo, the article is written in a "post-rigorous" style, great for people comfortable with the subject, and terrible from a pedagogical standpoint. To be clear though, it's exactly as you say: what they *really* show is that $\phi(A)$ is dense in $\tilde{A}$, not $A$ itself. The statement "Henceforth we identify $A$ with its copy" is meant to indicate that "$\phi(A)$ is now $A$".

Comment: Its really unconfortable. But ok, it's clear now!